# windbg stopped after I set up a breakpoint, keeping busing

Tags: reverse-engineering, windbg

I'm studying reverse engineering, I wrote the following code to see how it is to pass struct variables in the disassembly.

```
struct s {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct s get_some_values(int a)
{
    struct s rt;

    rt.a = a + 1;
    rt.b = a + 2;
    rt.c = a + 3;

    return rt;
}

int main()
{
    get_some_values(4);
}
```

The env is:

- win 7 x64
- windbg x86
- vs2017
- complied to debug, without aslr and dep
- command for the windbg after loaded the executable:

  - 0:000> bl
  - 0:000> x *!main
  - 00411770          returnvalue!main ()
  - 0:000> bp 0x00411770

Since then, at the left corner of windbg, its "BUSY", and not responding to any commands like 'g'.

Here's the screenshot:
[image: windbg stopped]

Any idea what I'm facing now?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works fine for me, same WinDbg version, Windows 7 SP1, but why don't you have symbols for your own exe? (`(no parameter info)`)

Comment: It is recommended to ask questions about Reverse Engineering in [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Megabeets: I think it's on-topic here, since Michael wrote his own code and is asking how to debug that.

Comment: @ThomasWeller a question indeed might be on-topic in two or more SE communities. Since OP is learning reverse engineering and since their question is about disassembly and debugging, I claim that the best place to ask is on the dedicated community for reverse engineering.